# OnChange event not firing on some android devices (Note4)

Tags: android, jquery, onchange

OnChange event working on most android devices but not working on some (namely note4).  I've tried adding the onChange attribute to the select tag with the same result.  Any idea why this isn't working on a few devices?

```
<select id="example" class="form-control">
 <option value="foo">bar</option>
</select>

$('#example').on('change', function() 
{

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
$('#example').on('change', function() 
{

});
```

Try this

```
$(document).on('change','#example', function() 
{

});
```